# is it possible to assign letters to a variable in cmd?

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

Because each time I try to assign a word to one it doesn't work and it results in 1, 2, 3 or 4 because there are 4 variables.

```
:foodrandom
set /a dish=0
set /a rfood1=4*%random%/32768+1
IF %rfood1%==1 set /a food1=carrots
IF %rfood1%==2 set /a food1=potatoes
IF %rfood1%==3 set /a food1=cabbage
IF %rfood1%==4 set /a food1=corn

set /a rfood2=4*%random%/32768+1
IF %rfood2%==1 set /a food2=hazelnuts
IF %rfood2%==2 set /a food2=acorns
IF %rfood2%==3 set /a food2=apples
IF %rfood2%==4 set /a food2=strawberries

set /a rfood3=4*%random%/32768+1
IF %rfood3%==1 set /a food3=parsley
IF %rfood3%==2 set /a food3=sage
IF %rfood3%==3 set /a food3=rosemary
IF %rfood3%==4 set /a food3=thyme

echo You make a nice meal from a few %rfood1%, some %rfood2% and scent it with some %rfood3%.

echo You win.
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
```

Comment: Please show the portion of the script which causes the problem.

Comment: Uodated: It's in the original text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to review the description of `SET` command.

`set variable=string` assigns the string to the variable. `set /A variable=expression` evaluate the arithmetic expression and assign the numeric result to the variable. In the expression you may use the value of another variable by just using its name.

So...

Your command `set /a food1=carrots` mean assign to `food1` the same numeric value of `carrots`; if this variable does not exists or contains a non-numeric value, assign a zero. Perhaps the intended result is `set food=carrots`?

Also, note that you are NOT displaying the value of `food1, food2 or food3` variables that supposedly contains the strings, you just show the values of the `rfood...` numeric variables...